# Retrieve AES key bytes

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, azure-keyvault

I have creead an AES key via the folloowing Azure CLI:

```
az keyvault key create --hsm-name myhsmkeyvault --name myaeskey2  --ops encrypt decrypt  --tags --kty oct-HSM --size 128
```

Now, I have this expectation, if I show the key, then I see the  `n` value (key byte) of this AES key. but the `n` value is null :

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "created": "2022-08-30T10:21:38+00:00",
    "enabled": true,
    "expires": null,
    "exportable": false,
    "notBefore": null,
    "recoverableDays": 7,
    "recoveryLevel": "CustomizedRecoverable",
    "updated": "2022-08-30T10:21:38+00:00"
  },
  "key": {
    "crv": null,
    "d": null,
    "dp": null,
    "dq": null,
    "e": null,
    "k": null,
    "keyOps": [
      "encrypt",
      "decrypt"
    ],
    "kid": "https://myhsm.managedhsm.azure.net/keys/myaeskey2/88adxxxxx2865",
    "kty": "oct-HSM",
    "n": null,
    "p": null,
    "q": null,
    "qi": null,
    "t": null,
    "x": null,
    "y": null
  },
  "managed": null,
  "releasePolicy": null,
  "tags": null
}
```

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Get Key` operation only returns the public portions of keys.

From [the `Get Key` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/get-key/get-key):

> If the requested key is symmetric, then no key material is released in the response.

The idea behind Key Vault is that keys don't leave the vault. Instead you're intended to send [ENCRYPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/encrypt/encrypt?tabs=HTTP)/[DECRYPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/decrypt/decrypt?tabs=HTTP) requests to have data encrypted/decrypted by the service.

From [the "Key Operations" section of the "Key types, algorithms, and operations" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/about-keys-details#key-operations):

> Key Vault doesn't support EXPORT operations. Once a key is provisioned in the system, it cannot be extracted or its key material modified.

An alternative approach is generating AES key locally, and then using the Key Vault [WRAP/UNWRAP operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/wrap-key/wrap-key) to encrypt the key before storing/transmitting it.

If you're using Python, see the documentation for [`wrap_key()`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-keyvault-keys/latest/azure.keyvault.keys.crypto.html#azure.keyvault.keys.crypto.CryptographyClient.wrap_key) and [`unwrap_key()`](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-keyvault-keys/latest/azure.keyvault.keys.crypto.html#azure.keyvault.keys.crypto.CryptographyClient.unwrap_key).

Example usage would be something like:

```py
from azure.keyvault.keys.crypto import KeyWrapAlgorithm

# Create CryptographyClient instance.
key_id = "https://<your vault>.vault.azure.net/keys/<key name>/fe4fdcab688c479a9aa80f01ffeac26"
crypto_client = CryptographyClient(key_id, credential)

# Generate a 32-byte (256-bit) AES key.
key_bytes = secrets.token_bytes(32)

# Wrap the AES key.
wrap_result = client.wrap_key(KeyWrapAlgorithm.rsa_oaep, key_bytes)
encrypted_key = wrap_result.encrypted_key

# At this point, you can safely store/transmit the encrypted_key for later
# usage. In addition, using Key Vault in this manner allows enforcing
# access controls, logging usage, etc. 

# When you want to use the key, you have to unwrap it.
unwrap_result = client.unwrap_key(KeyWrapAlgorithm.rsa_oaep, encrypted_key)
key = unwrap_result.key
```

I'm not super familiar with PySpark, but you'll probably want to convert the  key to a [BINARY literal format](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/data-types/binary-type.html) before using it in an expression. This sidesteps any potential issues with implicit crosscasting of STRING to BINARY.

```py
import binascii
key_hex = f"X'{binascii.hexlify(key)}'"
```

---

Also note that [the `key` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/get-key/get-key?tabs=HTTP#keybundle) contains a [JSON Web Key (JWK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keys/get-key/get-key?tabs=HTTP#jsonwebkey). The `n` property within the JWK is for an RSA modulus, while the `k` field would contain the symmetric key, if it were populated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your post. Let me explain my target: 
I would like to use [aes_encryption](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions/aes_encrypt.html) function in pyspark. This function needs key as BINARY expression. Before your post, I thought, that I can extract binary value of an AES key from KEyvault and put it in this function. But you mean that I should generate an AES key Locally and wrap it via an RSA key which is in Key vault, and then give it to this function? Can you please explain what exactly Keywrap mean?

Comment: Or the AES Key can also places in Key vault?

Comment: It looks like Key Vault supports either RSA or AES keys for performing key wrapping, although the latter only when using managed HSM. See [the summary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/about-keys-details#key-operations). I've updated the answer to try to explain/demonstrate how key wrapping might be utilized in your use case.